# WLST: Remote deployment of an application on weblogic

Tags: deployment, weblogic, wlst

I am trying to deploy an application remotely on WebLogic. I am using WLST in a python script.

I am using deploy command to do that. When I give the path of my war of any location which is accessible to my remote machine all goes well, but when I give any location which is not accessible to remote machine it fails.

Now I know the solution that by default upload is false hence the remote WebLogic needs an access to the war location, but I have tried it with setting upload true but still deployment fails with an error like:

> Deployment Message     : weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149003]Unable to access application source information in '/app/jamagentAdminServer.war' for application 'jamagent_AdminServer'. The specific error is: No application files exist.
>   No stack trace available.

Am I missing something? I am using the command:

> deploy('jamagent_'+ServerName,jamagentwarpath+'/jamagent'+ServerName+'.war', targets=ServerName, timeout=600000, upload='true')

so if I remove `upload='true'` clause and make sure that `jamagentwarpath` is a location accessible to remote machine, then everything goes fine. I hope I am clear with my question.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used the python version, but according to the [weblogic.Deployer Command-Line Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/deployment/wldeployer.html), which should be the identical functionality, you need the `-remote` option in addition to the `-upload` option:

> Indicates that weblogic.Deployer is not running on the same machine as the Administration Server, and that source paths specified in the command are valid for the Administration Server machine itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `upload='true'` option and specify `remote='true'` instead.

The "upload" option must be used when you have the application files on the machine where you execute the wlst script and you want to transfer them on the WL administrative machine.

The "remote" option tells the "deploy" command to not search the path in the local machine (where you execute the wlst script), but to search the path on the WL administrative machine.

The "remote" option  is available only on WLS 10.0 or higher. See [WLS 10.0 WLST deploy command reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1024285).